# Migrating SPSS syntax to R (Tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I decide to move away from SPSS to R (due to $$$). However I´m trying to map how I was doing stuff. So for example, and preferably using tidyverse, how can I rewrite these examples of syntax:

```
1. Recode variable
recode agevar (10 thru 20 = 1).
recode agevar (21 thru 30 = 2).

2. Recode into value
if (var1 = 1) newvar= var3.

3. Count (count how many times a value appears in a set of columns)
count newvar1 = var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 (1). #values equal to 1
count newvar1 = var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 (2 thru 5). #values from 2 to 5 inclusive
```

So I'm looking at easy ways to do this without deviating from tidyverse.

Comment: A reproducible example along with expected output would have helped.

Comment: For 2.: what value do you want newvar to take when var1 is not equal to 1?

Comment: For 1.: `agevar <- (agevar > 20) + 1` or `mutate(data, agevar = (agevar > 20) + 1)`

Comment: For 3.: `sum(unlist(select(data, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)) == 1)`

Comment: and the other one: `sum(dplyr::between(unlist(select(data, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)), 2, 5))`